# How to disable authentication requirement for VirtualBox's shared folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, virtualbox, shared-folders

After adding a shared folder in VirtualBox, I am able to access it like `admin:///media/sf_MyFolder/`, however, Ubuntu asks me to enter admin's password, even twice.

How to mount a VirtualBox's shared folder so that it can be accessed without authentication by a non-admin user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found the solution [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders):

> Note: Access to auto-mounted shared folders is only granted to the user
>   group vboxsf, which is created by the VirtualBox Guest Additions
>   installer. Hence guest users have to be member of that group to have
>   read/write access or to have read-only access in case the folder is
>   not mapped writable.

From the terminal, you can enter:

```
sudo adduser <username> vboxsf
```

Reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not working for CentOS guest machines.

Answer (score 0):

For existing users try:

```bash
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf username
```

Comment: That’s what `sudo adduser <username> vboxsf` does; it adds the `vboxsf` group to the given user, it doesn’t create a new user.